# Notifications do not work when downloading from the Play Market

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-application

When I launch the app for the first time from the Play Market (Google Play Console - internal testing), the following error appears:

```
2021-07-30 17:02:58.879 17789-17816/? W/Firebase-Installations: Firebase options used while communicating with Firebase server APIs: AIzaSyAcvhPbylYICEJB1VgbRQDAl27z-Z_...., flopi-72..., 1:963129640472:android:a45de9213a646f783d....
2021-07-30 17:02:58.879 17789-17816/? E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.**
...
 E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: FIS_AUTH_ERROR. Won't retry the operation.
```

What I tried: reinstalled the Android application in the Fiberbase project, changed the Android key in the Google Play Console, downloaded the google-services file.json, each time clearing the project from the files generated by Android Studio.

After that, it works for me in the debugging and release versions, as well as if I install an apk file. I don't receive notifications only when I download from the Play Market.

Comment: I found a solution: in the google-services file.the wrong WebKey value was passed to json - it was taken from the "Google Play Console", and the correct one turned out to be the one stored in "Firebase"